# enable or disable row editable per row based on condition infragistic grid

Tags: angular, grid, infragistics, igx-grid

I need to make a row editable based on grid data.  Some rows will be editable and some will not.  I tried cellEditExit/cellEdit event and tried to cancel the event but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using (rowEditEnter) and (cellEditEnter) is the correct approach. I am surprised that it didn't worked:

```html
<igx-grid [data]="data" height="550px" primaryKey="ProductID"
        [rowEditable]="true"
        (rowEditEnter)="rowEditEnter($event)"
        (cellEditEnter)="cellEditEnter($event)"
...
```

```
public rowEditEnter(evt) {
    evt.cancel = true;
}
public cellEditEnter(evt) {
    evt.cancel = true;
}
```

You can use this [sample and topic](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/editing#event-cancelation) as a reference and understand the event cancelation [sequence](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/editing#event-arguments-and-sequence).

Which version of the product are you using? My recommendation is to use the latest version of 11.1.7